# Database performance difference in performance: a lot of small operations vs some larger operations

Tags: sql-server, performance, entity-framework, performance-testing, database-performance

I'm currently debugging some performance issues for an application that is build in .net core using SQL Server as the underlying database, and Entity Framework Core as the ORM.

I have written a small console-application to simulate some workloads:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1;      

sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

Console.WriteLine("==== Table1 (1000000) key-lookup ====");

var sw1 = new Stopwatch();
sw1.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Value FROM table1 WHERE Id='" + i + "'";
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

     sqlConnection1.Open();

     reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

     var result = reader.Read();

     if (result)
     {
         var test = reader.GetString(0);
     }

     sqlConnection1.Close();
}

sw1.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Finished: " + sw1.Elapsed);
Console.WriteLine("==== Table2 (1000) full-text-scan ====");

var sw2 = new Stopwatch();
sw2.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM table2 WHERE Name LIKE '%" + i + "%'";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

    sqlConnection1.Open();

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    var result = reader.Read();

    if (result)
    {
        var test = reader.GetString(0);
    }

    sqlConnection1.Close();
}

sw2.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Finished: " + sw2.Elapsed);
Console.ReadKey();
```

To simulate Entity Framework I have opened and closed the connection for each query.

The application in installed on server1, and the database is located on the database server, when I run this application I get the following results:

My machine (app + SQL Server on same system):

- Key-seek: 1m53s
- Full-text: 4m31s

Server1 (app, db via network):

- Key-seek: 30m49s (!!!!)
- Full-text: 9m19s

Database server:

- Key-seek: 7m07s
- Full-text: 8m45s

The difference seems to be networking-related, but the servers are all just VM's sitting on the same hardware. Does anyone has an idea, what could be causing this poor performance the the app server?

Comment: I suggest parameterized queries if you're trying to simulate EF. That might improve performance a little but the number of round trips will be the long pole in the tent. FWIW, you should be able to achieve over 2K trivial queries per second over a 1gb network with a single-threaded app on common hardware. That's about what you are seeing locally on the db server so the VM isn't what it could be.

Comment: So you demonstrated that network traffic takes time. That's not new. The rest can probably be attributed to named-pipe protocol vs TCP/IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like this stanza:

> To simulate Entity Framework I have opened and closed the connection for each query.

Creating and closing connections is quite "expensive" process, therefore there is a [Connection pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) software design pattern. See [Using Connection Pooling with SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(VS.80).aspx) article for details.

Also it is not recommended to have load generator (in your case - command-line application) and SQL server instance on the same host to avoid mutual interference and clash in using operating system resources.

I would suggest using a 3rd-party tool i.e. [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) which provides [JDBC Request sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) for conducting the load, this way you will get more clear view of the query response times and will be able to correlate increasing response time with the increasing load. When you get to the point where response times will exceed acceptable thresholds (aka "bottleneck") you will be able to see the underlying reason and resolve it by either adding more resources or amending your SQL server connection configuration or optimizing queries.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of small operations is clearly worse than a few large operations. Any query you run against the SQL Server will have some network related overhead.

I am not familiar with VMs administration, but regardless of them sitting on the same physical server or not, there will be overhead associated with TCP-IP communication. Fast queries will suffer significant communication overhead.

An interesting test would be to divide your queries in batches. One quick way (statement construction only):

```
const int batchSize = 100;
for (int j = 0; j < batchSize; j ++)
{
    string inStr = string.Join("AND ", $"Name LIKE '%{i+j}%'");
    cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT Name FROM table2 WHERE 1 = 1 {inStr}";
}
```

<s>Also, an important thing to know if you use connection pooling or not. If you DO NOT use it, closing the connection is really expensive in your scenario (open connection, run a query, close it).</s> I have noticed your connection string and it looks that you are using connection pooling (active by default).